# Django: How to delete any foreign key object that is no longer referenced

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have nested data in my Django Rest Framework app, something like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    studyGroup = models.ForeignKey(StudyGroup, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  blank=True, null=True, related_name='student')
```

Each student may have a study group; a student may have no study group.

Many students can have the same study group.

I would like to automatically delete any StudyGroup that is not referenced by any students, either because the student was deleted or because it was updated.

I think this can be done by customising the 'save' and 'delete' methods for Student, checking whether their StudyGroup is referenced by any other Student, and deleting it if is not referenced. Or perhaps more elegantly by using signals. But it feels like there should be a simpler way to do this - like an inverse of  `on_delete=models.CASCADE`.

Is there a way to tell the database to do this automatically? Or do I need to write the custom code?

Comment: Shouldn't the `related_name` of your `ForeignKey` be `student_set` or `students`? The `related_name` is the name of the relation in *reverse*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `StudyGroup` objects that are no longer referenced by a `Student` with the following query:

```
StudyGroup.objects.filter(students__isnull=True).delete()
```

(this given the [**`related_name=`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) of your [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) is set to `'students'`, since this is the name of the relation in reverse).

Depending on the database backend, you could implement a *trigger* that can perform certain actions, for example when you remove/update an `Student` record. But that is backend-specific.

We can add a trigger to the `Student` model to remove the `StudyGroup`s without a `Student` when we delete or save `Student`s:

```
# app/signals.py

from app.models import Student
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver([post_delete, post_save], sender=Student)
def update_delete_student(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    StudyGroup.objects.filter(students__isnull=True).delete()
```

You will need to import the `signals` module in your application config:

```
# app/app.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):

    # ...

    def ready(self):
        import app.signals
```

But there are ways to bypass the Django signals through the ORM. For examply by using [**`QuerySet.update`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update).

Therefore it might be useful to run the method periodically, for example each day/hour. We can use [**`celery`** for that [realpython]](https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/) or [**`django-periodically`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/hzdg/django-periodically).

That being said, it might not be per se the most necessary to remove the `StudyGroup`s anyway. If you for example want to retrieve a `QuerySet` of `StudyGroup`s that have at least one student, we can write this like:

```
# StudyGroups with at least one Student
StudyGroup.objects.filter(student__isnull=False).distinct()
```

So instead of *removing* the `StudyGroup`s, you might decide not to show these `StudyGroup`s, like a [*soft delete* [wiktionary]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soft_deletion). Then you can still recover the data later on, this of course depends on the use case.

> **Note**: the `related_name` of a `ForeignKey` is the name of the relation in reverse, so the name of the attribute of a `StudyGroup` to retrieve the `QuerySet` of `Student`s. Therefore naming this `'studyGroup'` is a bit "*weird*". It would also easily result in *collisions* if there are two or more `ForeignKey`s that point to `StudyGroup` with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I had to make a couple of changes. First, to import from the same folder, I needed to write 'from . import signals' instead of 'import app.signals'. Also, I found that the app config in apps.py does not seem to run by default! I had to add: default_app_config = 'myappname.apps.MyAppConfigConfig' into __init__.py. Then it all works beautifully.

Comment: @LittleBrain: ah yes that might be necessary. You're welcome.